# Tratando de hacer un datatable en Rails 6.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hola Estoy tratando de hacer un Datatable , me sale este error.

```
rooms:101 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).DataTable is not a function
    at rooms:101:28
```

que apunta a esta linea [image: Imagen que se vee el error linea 101]

estoy utilizando dos gemas:

```
ajax-datatables-rails
jquery-datatables
```

la ajax-datatables-rails la configure completa pero la segunda creo que tengo configurado pero habla en la documentacion de la gema que debo ir:

JavaScripts
Incluya el JavaScript en su app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require datatables
```

crear nuevo archivoapp/assets/javascripts/datatables.js

```
//Core component
//= require datatables/jquery.dataTables
//Bootstrap4 theme
//= require datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4

//Optional Datatables extensions
//= require datatables/extensions/Responsive/dataTables.responsive
//= require datatables/extensions/Responsive/responsive.bootstrap4
//= require datatables/extensions/Buttons/dataTables.buttons
//= require datatables/extensions/Buttons/buttons.html5
//= require datatables/extensions/Buttons/buttons.print
//= require datatables/extensions/Buttons/buttons.bootstrap4
```

pero no encuentro las carpetas solo hay tres

[image: Carpeta en javascripts]

he seguido las instrucciones en la documentación de ajax-datatables-rails. y tambien he seguido como ejemplo de esta pagina https://sameer-kumar-1612.medium.com/datatable-on-rails-e371fe5a747d

Necesito que funcione si me pueden ayudar a realizarlo

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente no es la respuesta que esperas, pero no cabía en un comentario.
En general el integrar librerías js en sprockets a través de gemas es algo que cada vez se aconseja menos, de hecho desde Rails 7, [Sprockets ya se ha vuelto opcional](https://www.mintbit.com/blog/rails-7-dot-0-makes-sprockets-an-optional-dependency). En particular para tu caso, en la doc de [jquery-datatables](https://github.com/mkhairi/jquery-datatables#requirements) ya dicen que para Rails 6 sería bueno que manejaras esa dependencia a través de Webpacker (también vale destacar que el que la gema [no haya sido actualizada en los últimos 2 años](https://github.com/mkhairi/jquery-datatables/commits/master), es un indicador de que ya no es muy usada por la comunidad).
Luego, veo que `ajax-datatables-rails` funciona a nivel de controlador, así que no parece estar atada a la gema `jquery-datatables`, sino que parece poder funcionar sin problemas directamente con la librería js.
Independiente de eso, no se cual es el problema en particular, pero creo que podrías basarte en [la app de ejemplo](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails-sample-project) que `ajax-datatables-rails` linkea [en su documentación](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails#description). De hecho esa app integra datatables [a través de webpacker](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails-sample-project/blob/master/config/webpack/webpack.config.js#L7) y [no con jquery-datatables](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails-sample-project/blob/master/Gemfile).

Comment: holaAlter Lagos, intente bajar el ejemplo que me diste pero ocupa un gema datatables_factory que no existe en el https://rubygems.org/ como lo puedo hacer

Comment: No existe, pero ese no es el problema, porque es descargado de github, pero está refierendo a un commit que no existe. Borra la definición completa de `datatables-factory` desde tu [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails-sample-project/blob/master/Gemfile.lock#L8-L14) y luego llama `bin/bundle install` nuevamente. Eso debería permitirme instalar las gemas

Comment: Igual [creé un issue](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails-sample-project/issues/1) en el repo del proyecto para que lo arreglen.

Comment: Gracias oye borre la gema e intente implementar sin el jquery pero no me da error y no me carga que puede ser

Comment: Sin mayor información, no se cómo pueda ayudarte. Podrías crear una nueva pregunta donde compartas más en detalle lo que hiciste y lo que te está fallando. En lo personal, nunca he usado esa librería, así que no es que conozca posibles errores que pudiesen suceder.